# Using Tidyverse tools (dplyr, purrr, etc.), how to replace ugly coded values for the human-readable values from the database dictionary?

Tags: r, dictionary, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I have two files: a .csv file that has ugly numbered files and a dictionary. Here's a similar and  simplified example of the .csv file:

```
responses <- tribble(
  ~n_case, ~movie, ~song, ~sex,
  1, 2, 2, 0,
  2, 1, 1, 0,
  3, 2, 4, 1
  
)
```

And here's a similar and simplified example of the dictionary database:

```
# Note the jump from 2 to 4 in 'song' is deliberate,
# as this appears in the actual database that I am working with
dic <- tribble(
  ~name, ~value, ~tag,
  "movie", 1, "Shrek",
  "movie", 2, "Lego",
  "song", 1, "Hallelujah",
  "song", 2, "Happy Birthday",
  "song", 4, "Melancholy Hill",
  "sex", 0, "male",
  "sex", 1, "female"
)
```

What could I do to replace the ugly "values" by the human-readable "tags"?
I'd like to arrive at this:

```
> responses_human
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  n_case movie song            sex   
   <dbl> <chr> <chr>           <chr> 
1      1 Lego  Happy Birthday  male  
2      2 Shrek Hallelujah      male  
3      3 Lego  Melancholy Hill female
```

In case you're curious, I am working with [Guatemala's person census](https://www.censopoblacion.gt/descarga) (as opposed to house or home census).

I tried solving my problem by filtering each 'name' (survey question's answers; i.e. "movie", "song", "sex"), grabbing the result and creating a new tibble out of that. That way, I'd end up with dozens of tibbles, each being a mini-dictionary for each survey question's answers (movie, song, sex, etc.). Then, I'd `left_join` these filtered mini-dictionaries, one by one, resulting in dozens of new human-readable columns. I'd then appropriately `rename` and `select` the columns so that I'd get rid of the ugly numbers and only keep the human-readable "tags".

However, this solution requires naming dozens of variables and is therefore a slow process. Note that there are 84 variables, each with multiple numbered/ugly "values" and human-readable "tags". Moreover, I will probably use the other (house and home) censuses, which pose the same problem.

I have a hunch that there's a much more efficient and automated way of doing this. I just don't know what it is yet.

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to first split your data dictionary into a `list` containing a recoding vector per `name`. In a second step you could use this `list` inside `across` to recode the columns of your dataset:

```r
library(dplyr, w = FALSE)
library(tibble)

dic_split <- split(dic, dic$name) %>%
  lapply(function(x) {
    x %>%
      select(-name) %>%
      tibble::deframe()
  })

rec_helper <- function(x, col) {
  recode(x, !!!dic_split[[col]])
}

responses %>%
  mutate(across(
    all_of(intersect(names(dic_split), names(responses))),
    ~ rec_helper(.x, cur_column())
  ))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>   n_case movie song            sex   
#>    <dbl> <chr> <chr>           <chr> 
#> 1      1 Lego  Happy Birthday  male  
#> 2      2 Shrek Hallelujah      male  
#> 3      3 Lego  Melancholy Hill female
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It worked out well for the simplified tibbles. However, when I ran the equivalent code on the census data, I got 9 identical warning messages:
```
1: Problem while computing `..1 = across(...)`.
ℹ Unreplaced values treated as NA as `.x` is not compatible. 
```

Do you know what this could be? Is there a way of avoiding its underlying cause by changing the code you suggested?

Comment: Hi Gabriel. The issue is most likely that you data dictionary does not contain "labels" for all "values". That's what the warning is telling us, i.e. there were unreplaced values which were replaced by NAs (because the raw data is numeric, but the labels are characters). One possible option would be to convert to a character before recoding, e.g. try `recode(as.character(x), !!!dic_split[[col]])`. However, IMHO you should have a closer look at your data and check what's reason for this. I would guess that the unreplaced are some kind of missings.

Answer (score 3):

You could go long, join, wide:

```r
library(tidyverse)

responses |>
  pivot_longer(-n_case) |>
  left_join(dic, by = c("name", "value")) |>
  select(-value) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = tag)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   n_case movie song            sex   
#>    <dbl> <chr> <chr>           <chr> 
#> 1      1 Lego  Happy Birthday  male  
#> 2      2 Shrek Hallelujah      male  
#> 3      3 Lego  Melancholy Hill female
```

or with factor:

```r
responses |>
  mutate(across(movie:sex, \(x) as.character(factor(x,
                                                    levels = dic[dic$name == cur_column(),]$value,
                                                    labels = dic[dic$name == cur_column(),]$tag))))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   n_case movie song            sex   
#>    <dbl> <chr> <chr>           <chr> 
#> 1      1 Lego  Happy Birthday  male  
#> 2      2 Shrek Hallelujah      male  
#> 3      3 Lego  Melancholy Hill female
```

Comment: You do not need the `select` part

Comment: @onyambu If you remove the select, you do not get the desired output.

Comment: Am pretty sure you do. Pivot_wider will automatically drop the values column. As long as you specify the id cols.

Answer (score 1):

You can reshape the dictionary to wide format and then use it to lookup values across your response data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dic_wide <- dic %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = tag)

responses %>%
  mutate(across(-n_case, ~ dic_wide[[cur_column()]][match(.x, dic_wide$value)]))

# A tibble: 3 × 4
  n_case movie song            sex   
   <dbl> <chr> <chr>           <chr> 
1      1 Lego  Happy Birthday  male  
2      2 Shrek Hallelujah      male  
3      3 Lego  Melancholy Hill female
```